# React, how to know when a pure function component has been rendered?

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a library that logs when components get re-rendered, so I need to detect that.

I can do it for components that extends `React.Component` by monkey-patching `React.Component.prototype.componentDidUpdate`, but how can I detect when a pure function component gets rendered? Is that even possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since function components don't use inheritance and lifecycle hooks, it isn't possible to patch them without modifying component source code.

It's possible to use API that is used by React dev tools to access React renderer, a hook is assigned to `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__`, then it is caught up by React renderer. A good example is `react-render-hook`. It doesn't provide needed functionality itself but can be modified to requirements, specifically [this line](https://github.com/bruderstein/react-render-hook/blob/ffea5a2df184e574e90a2e2b5eec154c5d302307/src/globalHook.js#L63-L65).